# python change the list's values based on a for loop(or other suitable method)

Tags: python, list

I need to change the list's value to 0 if the input is below 0, and change it to 255 if the input is above 255.
i.e. if the list is [265,45,-23], I need to change it to [255,45,0].
Tried to figure it out for hours, but gave up a bit (the initial input is a tuple). Here is my code so far, but I have no idea which logic I should use:

```
   def rgb(r, g, b):
    x = (r,g,b)
    x = list(x)
    for i in x:
        if i<0:
            x=0
        if i>255:
            x=255
    print(x)
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `x = [r, g, b]` instead of creating a tuple and changing it to a list?

Comment: @Barmar Should have :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in a single line using a list comprehension:

```
def rgb(r,g,b): return [min(255,max(0,n)) for n in (r,g,b)]
```

Output:

```
rgb(265,45,-23) 

[255, 45, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the tuple. Try this:

```
def rgb(r, g, b):
    x = [r,g,b]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i] < 0:
            x[i] = 0
        if x[i] > 255:
            x[i] = 255
    return x
# Output: [255, 45, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you assign to `x` you're replacing the whole variable with a new value, not just the current element of the iteration.

You can use `enumerate()` to get the list index and value together, and use the index in the assignment.

```
for i, val in enumerate(x):
    if val < 0:
        x[i] = 0
    elif val > 255:
        x[i] = 255
```

You can also use a list comprehension:

```
x = [min(255, max(0, val)) for val in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max(0, min(255, x))` for a list element `x`. Then for the whole list you can use a list comprehension:

```
x = [max(0, min(255, y)) for y in x]
```

Alternatively you can use the ternary operator:

```
x = [255 if y > 255 else (0 if y < 0 else y) for y in x]
```

Comment: Doesn't the ternary operator always return either 0 or 255 (no other values)?

Comment: @JohnDoe `a if b else c` will first evaluate `b` and if it's true it will evaluate and yield `a` otherwise it will evaluate and yield `c`. Here `a, b, c` can be expressions and in your example we have `a = 255`, `b = y > 0` and `c = (0 if y < 0 else y)` which is a whole ternary expression on it's own (and hence follows the same rules). So in case `y > 0` is false `(0 if y < 0 else y)` will be evaluated and if also `y < 0` is false (that means now `0 <= y <= 255`) then just `y` itself will be yielded.

Comment: Am I missing something? Tried your method with this code: def rgb(r,g,b):
    x = [r,g,b]
    x = [255 if y > 0 else (0 if y < 0 else y) for y in x]
    return x
Then called the rgb function with parameters (120,20,254) and the output was [255,255,255]...

Comment: @JohnDoe Oh yeah, thanks for pointing that out, I had a typo it should've been `y > 255` instead of `y > 0`. Now I also understand your first comment, and you were right, in the previous version it would always return either 0 or 255. Thanks again, I fixed my answer.

Comment: Ooh, ok, great! Can't beleive I didn't figure that out myself, quite an obvious typo. Well, nvm, looks like we both need to be a bit more attentive :) . No problem, thank you for the clarification, it all makes perfect sense now!

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to go through `r`, `g` and `b`. And at the same time create a new list that tests the conditions.

```
def rgb(r, g, b):
    return [0 if x < 0 else 255 if x > 255 else x for x in (r,g,b)]
```

You can call it like:

```
print(rgb(265,45,-23))
```

or like:

```
x = [265,45,-23]
print(rgb(*x))
```

Comment: You have a typo, it should be `... else 255 ...` instead of `... 255 else ...`. Right now it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
def rgb(r, g, b):
    rgb_tuple = (r,g,b)
    rgb_list = list(rgb_tuple)
    new_list = []
    for color in rgb_list:
        if color<0:
            new_list.append(0)
        elif color>255:
            new_list.append(255)
        else:
            new_list.append(color)
    print(new_list)
    return new_list

rgb(266, 80, -9)
```

Comment: way too long of an answer all the other answers are much shorter, i suggest u edit it